# docker image network set to host mode, but cannot access from my comouter

Tags: docker, centos7

I have started a centos7 image on my docker and set the network mode to host, then I start a service on port 9090 in this container, but I can't access this service from outside by using localhost:9090, but I can access this service in the container (docker vserion 18.03)

Comment: Which OS? What version of docker? Docker toolbox or something else? Please update your complete setup

Comment: can you share the output of `netstat -tlnp | grep 9090` from your host-machine ?

Comment: thank you for answering me, I find this out by my self, my host os is macOS, but host mode doesn't support macOS